# return js value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

First tentative steps into client side. I'm having trouble finishing the following. My question is how do I return the value of a function in a HTML statement ...

```
<script language="Javascript">
function checkjava()
{
 return 1
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="enabled_catch.php" method="get" name="your_form">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="answer" value="RETURN checkjava() HERE")>
<input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
</body>
```

I'd appreciate your help
Thanks in advance

G

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
  <script language="Javascript">
    function checkjava() {
      return 1
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="enabled_catch.php" 
        method="get" 
        name="your_form"
        onsubmit="this.answer.value=checkjava();">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" value="click me">
  </form>
</body>
```

No need for the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="enabled_catch.php" method="get" name="your_form" >
<input type="HIDDEN" name="answer" value="RETURN checkjava() HERE")>
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('answer').value=checkjava();"  value="click me">
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser-side scripting is event driven. Unless an event is triggered, nothing happens.

You could listen to the `click` event on your submit button, and then manipulate the value of your hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer" value="")>
<input type="submit" value="click me" 
       onclick="document.getElementById('answer').value = checkjava();">
```

Note how we had to give an `id` to the hidden field, in order to be able to reference it with `getElementById()`.

Also note that JavaScript is case sensitive: `checkjava()` and `checkJava()` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like that:

```
<script language="Javascript">
  function checkjava()
  {
   return 1
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <form action="enabled_catch.php" method="get" name="your_form" onsubmit="document.getElementById('answer').value=checkjava();">
  <input type="HIDDEN" id="answer" >
  <input type="submit" value="click me">
 </form>
</body>
```

Basically on form submit you would set the value of the `answer` input to the result of the function call.

EDIT: placed onsubmit on the wrong element before (embarrassing).

Comment: And by removing the `name`-attribute from the `hidden` input you might have made it impossible to find the value in `enable_catch.php`

Answer (score 0):

I would have an id on the answer tag and then do it in the form onsubmit event.

Something like:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById("answerId").value = checkJava()" action="enabled_catch.php" method="get" name="your_form">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="answer" id="answerId" value="RETURN checkjava() HERE")>
<input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.your_form.answer.value = checkjava();
</script>
```

Unless you want to use a fancy JS library. =)